# How to edit a post's caption with Instagram API or any other method available without using Instagram App

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, caption

I'm trying to find a way to edit an authorized user's post's caption, but it doesn't seem like the API supports this. How can I do it i'm authorized?

Or

What endpoint does the Instagram app post to when editing the caption. Maybe I can work around to recreate the environment like an App to post an edit.

Answer (score 4):

`Media's caption` is the `first owner's comment` on the media. You could try to get `id of caption` and delete it as [comment](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#delete_media_comments). To add new `caption`, just delete all comments on the media and add new comment. Of course, your application must have rights to `POST` and `DEL` comments and to get `user's content`.

Comment: Ok let me try that. Will accept if everything goes well.